# How to define a owl:imports with OWL API v3?

Tags: import, ontology, owl, owl-api

I am using OWL API 3.
I created a new ontology, but I do not understand how to associate a owl:imports with the ontology.

I used IRImappers but they did not work.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code:

```
OWLOntology ontology = manager.createOntology(ontologyIRI);

OWLImportsDeclaration importDeclaraton =
   factory.getOWLImportsDeclaration(importIRI); 

manager.applyChange(new AddImport(ontology, importDeclaraton));
```

Comment: the above example in the answer is working, but I'm being to query the ontology only after saving it and reloading it, is it possible to query the ontology just after adding the import

Comment: In order to have the imported ontology available right after creating the import directive, the imported ontology must already be loaded in the manager. This can be accomplished by calling `manager.loadOntology(`importIRI)`